# How to make joomla check different folder for html overrides first?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I am making system plugin for Joomla 2.5 and 3.x that should check for different html overrides folder first before the templates/template_name/html , it works well but I honestly do not like it because it is a hack that can be easily killed by joomla update. For example to override module chrome 
In my plugin I have :

```
public function onAfterInitialise() {
     JLoader::register('JModuleHelper','path to my application module helper');
}
```

and in my custom helper.php  I changed the **JModuleHelper** class method **renderModule()**  to check for html overrides in following order:

```
check my plugin html folder if module override file is there use it 
if no override in my plugin check template html folder 
if none of the above use joomla default.
```

joomla default is:

```
    check my template html folder if module override file is there use it 
   if no override in template html, use joomla default.
```

isn't there an easier way to achieve this ?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Why would you need to do this? A module can have multiple overrides.

Comment: It is not just module override I am after ,  need to do custom layouts override for all joomla extensions, module is just an example

Comment: Ok then, you can still accomplish this with the standard Joomla system. You can do multiple overrides for components, modules, and plugins. Beyond that, you can do page specific layouts with template styles or by making use of the page class in the menu item.

Comment: I don't think you understood the question. I want a reroute to my own plugin html folder first, to be first check , not joomla default. This is the whole point of making a plugin. Like this http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_component_mvc_from_the_Joomla!_core

Comment: Yes, I understand you want to check another folder for an override. My question is this - why not put that override in the standard place and save yourself the trouble? Everything in Joomla can be overridden by default, why make it look in a non-standard location when you can put it where it belongs?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve what I am after is this 
http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_component_mvc_from_the_Joomla!_core

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/style-a-design/templating/15611